# Display multiple variable data separately from multiple tables on single view in blade template in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to display two variable data on same view in a foreach loop

```php
    public function getWalletList()
    {
        $data = Data::orderBy('id','desc')->get()->toArray();
        $user_ids = array_column($data, 'id');
        $user_data = User::whereIn('id',$user_ids)->get()->toArray();
        $d= array('data'=>$data,'user'=>$user_data);
        return view('wallet_list', compact('d'));
    }
```

So how to diplay data on laravel blade template

```html
@foreach($d as $value)                                        
    <tr>
        <td>{{$value['wallet']['name']}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->user_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->price}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->price}}</td>
        <td>{{$value->updated_at}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use two foreach ?

```
   @foreach($d as $value)                                        
      <tr>
         <td>{{$value['wallet']['name']}}</td>
         <td>{{$value->user_id}}</td>
         <td>{{$value->price}}</td>
         <td>{{$value->price}}</td>
         <td>{{$value->updated_at}}</td>
      </tr>
   @endforeach
   @foreach($b as $value)                                        
      <tr>
         <td>{{$value['wallet']['name']}}</td>
         <td>{{$value->user_id}}</td>
         <td>{{$value->price}}</td>
         <td>{{$value->price}}</td>
         <td>{{$value->updated_at}}</td>
      <tr>
   @endforeach
```